# [0, 1].forEach((e) => {console.log(e)}) producing TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

```js
[0, 1].forEach((e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

The code above is executing well in the inspector and prints out 0 and 1, but when I put it inside a `<script>` tag I get an

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Any ideas why?

I have workaround for this obviously but I'm just being curious.

In VSCode when I typed `[].forEach((e) => {console.log(e)})` I had red underline below [], maybe it's just the syntax? But why does it work in Chrome inspector?

Comment: Are you sure the error is from the same code? Because the snippet provided works fine.

Comment: I just tested this in the `<script>` tag of a simple web page and Chrome executed it fine without errors.

Comment: For me it is also working fine.

Comment: I suspect you had something on the line before this, so `[0, 1]` is being interpreted as a subscript, not an array.

Comment: Try adding a semicolon before the opening bracket. If that fixes things, it's because you're relying on ASI just a _little_ too much — there are cases where you do need a semicolon.

Comment: Zac Anger that was that, second time it happens to me. I'm quite new to JS and since I figured out (wrongly apparently) that semicolons were not mandatory I stopped using them in JS. Ty !